# Building Poco with cmake: MySQL Support Disabled - no MySQL library

Tags: mysql, cmake, mariadb, poco

The main goal is to build Poco Complete Edition libs for Ubuntu 16.04 and work.
If one reads the manual https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html everything looks very simple. But as always something very obvious to everyone but me was omitted and the recipe doesn't work.

What have I done? Of course, I've installed openssl, odbc, mysql-client and libmysqlclient-dev. After that I'm running "cmake .." and bash tells me

```
...
-- Couldn't find MySQL or MariaDB 
-- MySQL Support Disabled - no MySQL library
...
```

Ok, let's ignore that... Executig "make" and "make install". Success. But when I'm trying to write in Qt5

```
 #include <Poco/Data/MySQL/Connector.h>
```

It tells me, that no such header. Even MySQL folder.

Please, tell me, what have I missed? How should I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself. One should perform the binary installation of mysql, i.e. copy the tar-content into /usr/local/mysql, and at last poco's cmake will tell it has found MySQL.